# L-theory periodicity

Tags: homological-algebra, surgery-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category. I have two questions:

1. Is there a conceptual explanation why $L(\mathcal{A})$ is 4-periodic, in the sense that
   $L_{i}(\mathcal{A})=L_{i+4}(\mathcal{A})$ for any $i\in \mathbf{Z}$?
2. Suppose that $M\in \mathcal{A}$. In which sense can $M$ represent an element of the group $L_{0}(\mathcal{A})$?

Remark: AFAIK there are many different variations of $L$-theory groups. I will be happy if there are enlightening answers for question 1 and 2 for any chosen variation of $L$-theory group (symmetric, quadratic, …).

Comment: The motivating example is the duality of the homology of manifolds. Manifolds of dimension a **multiple of 4** have a quadratic form on their middle homology. $L$ theory is not defined for just an additive category, but requires extra structure, such as a symmetric monoidal structure. Also, pass to the derived category. An element of $L_0$ is not an object, but an object with a quadratic pairing $M\otimes M\to U$. Taking the suspensions of $U$ gives the 4 deloopings. If $M\otimes M\to U$, then $M[2]\otimes M[2]\to U[4]$. But it's not 2-periodic bc $M[1] switches symmetric and skew symmetric

Comment: @BenWieland it looks convincing as an evidence for 4-periodicity phenomenon. What is U? Are you sure that you always need an extra structure as tensor product? An involution seems enough generally? No? In case you insist on tensor product, does L(A) has a ring structure?

Comment: $U$ stands for the unit of the symmetric monoidal category. But you have to generalize to $U[n]$. Maybe any invertible element will do. Yes, this seems like too much structure. Maybe you just need a contravariant duality functor $D(X)=Hom(X,U)$ and an $L$-class is $f:X\to D(X)$. But you need to say that this is symmetric. It's clear what that means in a symmetric monoidal category. If you just assume $D(D(X))=X$, then you should ask $D(f)=f$, but maybe some higher coherence? Somehow to get the answer 4-periodic, the signs from shift should appear, to interchange symmetric and skewsymmetric.